# how long time "vuex-persistedstate" stores any value?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

Last few days exploring about Vue store management. Found this plugin named `vuex-persistedstate` to keep state persisted.

But noticed that it keeps all the value until I clear state functionally. So, I want to know is there any session for that stored state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vuex-persistedstate` use the browser local storage,

so there are two ways to clear `vuex-persistedstate` data

1. clear the state by using code whenever necessary
2. clear the browser cache